# How can I pass the results of an http request back from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

I am a beginner to Android and Java.  Not doing too bad so far but I have stumbled upon an issue that I can't wrap my head around.

I am trying to create a method in my application class that will do http calls with a value pair list passed to it. Here is the first part. This is in a activity that is activated by a button click.

```
  // Add your data to array
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "2"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cell", "2500270025"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "blah"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reason", "2"));

        // need to call the request
        String result = ((RespondApp) getApplication()).makeHTTPCall(nameValuePairs);
```

Once I get to the app here is the receiving part.

```
public String makeHTTPCall(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        // this will be used to make all http requests from the whole app       
        new postToHttp().execute(nameValuePairs);
        return null;        
    }
```

Here is the AsyncTask part.

```
class postToHttp extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // I am sure I need something here just don't know what
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.evfd.ca/cell.php");
            try {

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));
                Log.i("makeHttpCall", "done ecoding");
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.i("Read from server", result);
                return result;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I am trying to get the response sent back  by the webserver all the way back to the activity page that called this process.  So ideally I want to just load up the value pairs make the call and get the http response back, and then continue on my merry way.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the `String` you downloaded on the main UI thread right from the `AsyncTask` itself. Simply override `protected void onPostExecute(String result)` in your `AsyncTask` class and do the work there. This function will get called with whatever value you return from `doInBackground()`.

Basically, do whatever the next step is inside of `onPostExecute()`. See [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12575068/687315) for a few ideas:

- Nest the `AsyncTask` class as an inner class within your `Activity` so it can work with your Activity's variables, methods, etc.
- Create an `interface` that your Activity implements. Basically, the task would call something like `onHttpTaskComplete(String result)` in the Activity.